# Regarding publishing an app in the play store with the same package name

Tags: android

I wanted to upload a project onto the play store from the developer console.The issue is that the package name of my app has already been used by another app.Now  that another app has been unpublished.Now when i try to publish my app it still shows the error that "app containing the package name is present in the google play store".

Should i change the package name of my project(That is going to be the hard way)

or should i wait for some more hours and upload in the same package name?

Comment: you have to change only ur package name

Comment: But the duplicate app has been unpublished.Why cant i use the old package name?

Answer (score 1):

In Google Play you can't delete the app, you can only "disable", so the package will never be liberated.

So, there are 2 things now:

1. If the app plublished is yours, you can use the same package to make it as new version of the app.
2. If the app is not yours, you have to change your package. I recomend use some package as:
   `com.achuthan.XXXXX` (for example)

**How to change package:**

***Eclipse:***

Right click on your project, scroll down to Android Tools, and then click on Rename Application Package.
Then accep all changes, and in Manifest to.

***Android Studio: (bit more complicated)***

For example, com.example.app to io.awesome.game or something in-between, then:

1. In the Project pane, click on the little gear icon
2. Uncheck/Deselect the Compact Empty Middle Packages option
3. Your package directory will now be broken up in individual
       directories
4. Individually select each directory you want to rename, and:

   - Right-click it
   - Select Refactor
   - Click on Rename In the Pop-up dialog,click on Rename Package instead of Rename Directory
   - Enter the new name and hit Refactor
   - Allow a minute to let Android Studio update all changes
   - Note: When renaming com in Android Studio, it might give a
     warning. In such case, select Rename All
5. Now open your build.gradle (Usually 'app' or 'mobile'). Update the applicationId to your Package Name and Sync Gradle, if it hasn't already been updated automatically:

Comment: The issue is that is'nt it hard to change the package name of every file.Someone suggested going to android tools and selecting rename package.But will it affect all files.ALso i have generated an api key for google maps using old package name.Wont that be affected?

Comment: @AchuthanM what IDE are you using?

Comment: eclipse is the ide i am using

Comment: @AchuthanM simply select Package folder in left panel and go to top title bar choose Refractor>Rename , and rename your package , and don't forget to change in Manifest

Comment: should i change in every activity also?

Comment: You have to go to console api and generate new gen with the new package. Take the new key and change it for the old one